# Why does F#dim resolve to C/G?

Tags: theory, jazz

So heres my question:

F#dim -> C/G

How does this work?

Well I understand that F#dim is functioning as D7b9 and resolving to the G in C/G but my question is why? It would make perfect sense to me if it resolved to G, but no it "resolves" to C/G ... Can anyone explain this?

Comment: The linked question in comment above will answer your question. The chords in that question just happen to be transposed: Bdim7 => F/C rather than F#dim7 => C/G.

Comment: It may also be helpful to consider the notion of the "cadential six-four" discussed in [Analyzing an unfamiliar Roman numeral analysis: Cm/G-G notated as V6/4-5/3?](https://music.stackexchange.com/q/58536/21766).